# Footer is missing in magento checkout page-magento2

Tags: magento2

How to add footer in magento2 checkout page.it's missing

Answer (score 2):

Put below line in your custom theme just after body tag `app/design/frontend/Custom/default/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
    <body>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="false"/>
    ....
   </body>
```

**[EXTRA]** If you need header parts

```
<referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
<referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
<referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" />
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
```

[How to create custom theme](https://magenticians.com/magento-2-add-header-footer-checkout-page/)

run this command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: yes..it's working...

Comment: can you please guide me to remove email field from checkout page?

Comment: for remove email field please create new question

Comment: i can't create new question...can you please help me..?

Comment: Just go to top header right sidebar you will see **Ask Question** button click there, Also I would suggest you to accept this answer if it works